# Change point size of a ggplot object after being returned from a function

Tags: r, ggplot2

Suppose I have a function that returns a ggplot object:

```
getplot = function() {
    x = rnorm(16)
    y = rnorm(16)
    dat = data.frame(x, y)
    myplot = ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) + geom_point()
    myplot
}
```

After calling that function

```
x = getplot()
```

, how can I change the point size?

Comment: You can also include size argument in your function and let user to supply it in function `getplot()` call

Answer (score 8, accepted):

maybe you can use `update_geom_defaults` :

> Modify geom/stat aesthetic defaults for future plots

So to change size:

```
getplot()
update_geom_defaults("point",list(size=10))
```

Comment: spooky, how it modifies the printing of x previously created.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
x = getplot() + geom_point(size=N)
```